# How to remove hyperlink when user clicks it

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove the hyperlink after I click it. (pagination)

I want the hyperlink to be removed but still show the text.

```
<a href='#'>1</a>
<a href='#'>2</a>
<a href='#'>3</a>   //remove the hyperlink but keep number 3.
<a href='#'>4</a>
<a href='#'>5</a>
```

Thanks for the helps.

Comment: You'll also need to add the link back when a different number is clicked, otherwise you can only ever get to each page once unless you refresh the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr("href");
});
```

Comment: wth.. I was going to answer this a long time ago but it wasn't working in the fiddle. Now it is.. .. ... ... +1  http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/gGEgZ/

Answer (score 3):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/emucov/1/edit)*

```
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();          // if you need it
  $(this).contents().unwrap();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/contents/
http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mELzT/)

Comment: `$(this).replaceWith($(this).text());` - this would work better.

Comment: Because your current version replaces the `<a>` with itself -> in other words, it's pointless.

Comment: Oops, seems that I am. That's strange ;-) Still, either `.text()` or `.html()` would work.